# Getting position of elements in XML that refers to the element's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML.

```
<root>
    <item id="first"></item>
    <item id="second"></item>
    <item id="third"></item>

    <ref ids="first"></ref>
    <ref ids="first second"></ref>
    <ref ids="third"></ref>
</root>
```

I want to find position of `<ref>` elements which are refering to `<item>`.
It should look like this for XML above.

```
1,2
2
3
```

I tried to write XSLT for this but I have some problems.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="thisId" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name="references" select="/root/ref[contains(@ids, $thisId)]/position()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$references" separator=", " />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. If some id is substring of other one, contains() matches it - How
   can I avoid it?
2. position() always starts from 1 but I want real position of `<ref>` in XML.

Do you have any ideas how to ensure this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using **XSLT 2.0**, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="ref" match="ref" use="tokenize(@ids, ' ')" />

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', @id)/(count(preceding-sibling::ref) + 1)" separator=", " />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```